# 15.04 Only Boots in Recovery Mode After CPU Change

Tags: boot, 15.04, data-recovery, cpu, mode

I moved from an FX-6300 to an i5-4690k so I could have an ITX-size computer, and transplanted both the hard drive and the GPU. Gnome wasn't very happy about this, so now when I try to boot normally, it gets to the point with the Gnome foot and the three blinking dots under it, but after a moment the dots stop blinking and they all turn light. After that the computer just sits at that screen forever, not doing anything. I have found though if I boot into recovery mode, it goes through a bunch of scrolling text, and then it says something like "an error has occurred" and it gives me a list of things I can do to fix it, like updating GRUB or validating the packages.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot about i915 graphics needed to start a graphical shell such as gnome]

It works fine if I simply tell it to continue booting, but if I try to validate the packages it says it needs to download 1,250KB of data. I tell it to do that, and then it brings me back to the list of things I can do to solve the error. If I select validate packages again, it does the same thing, as if it was unsuccessful... What is happening here?

I'm trying to fix this because I'm moving from a 1TB HDD to a 500GB SSD at the same time (all the data will fit), and I want to get everything working before I copy it to the SSD. (It would also be helpful if anyone knew what software I can use to do this, but that's a different question).

Comment: Iit says something like "an error has occurred".   What is the exact error?

Comment: I am not sure how to interpreted the error. It starts with hda_snd (which I think is the intel chipset sound), but i915 also does things with build-n graphics. Which might explain the problems with starting a graphical shell (such as gnome).

Comment: Please boot your computer normally (as far as it goes), then reboot into recovery with network support and, from `/var/log/`, [upload](/q/440087/175814) `dmesg.0`, `kern.log`, and `syslog`. The latter two use `logrotate`, so, please verify, that the time stamps inside of them go back far enough to include the entire previous, normal boot. If not, you need to include `kern.log.1` and `syslog.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Boot with a live-dvd/usb

After the session load:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# fdisk -l
```

*Fdisk report hard disk partitions, suppose /, is /dev/sda1, continue running:*

```
# umount /dev/sda1
# fsck -y /dev/sda1
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
# mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# chroot /mnt
# dpkg --configure -a
# apt-get -f install
# apt-get -m install
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# apt-get install --reinstall gnome-desktop-environment gnome
# umount /mnt
# reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

O.K. Try this:

1. Reboot into recovery mode
2. Press enter on all of the following menu items (IN ORDER!!)

   1. `network`

      1. `yes`
   2. `root`
3. Type `apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell` and press enter
4. Type `y` if asked confirmation to reinstall
5. Type `reboot` press enter

If *that* didn't work try this:

1. Reboot into recovery mode
2. Press enter on all of the following menu items (IN ORDER!!)

   1. `network`

      1. `yes`
   2. `root`
3. Type `apt-get purge gnome-shell` and press enter
4. Type `y` if asked confirmation to remove
5. Type `apt-get install gnome-shell` and press enter
6. Type `y` if asked confirmation to install
7. Follow any onscreen prompts or instructions
8. Type `reboot` press enter

Comment: @Ben There is supposed to be a command line. Does the foot appear after or before you login?

Comment: @Ben Ok then try the new instructions

Comment: @Ben any luck with the new instructions?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do as you have changed both processor and motherboard is to do a backup of your data and do a clean install of the OS. Grab an Ubuntu 15.04 64bit install and you will have all your problems solved. You didnt change from intel to intel but from AMD to intel so the changes are bigger.

Comment: Why are you constantly recommending reinstallations?  There's usually not a need to do this.

Comment: Because it is a complete platform change.

Comment: @No, this is a Processor change.  Do you have evidence that this is a complete architecture change?  Do you know that the system is going from 64-bit to 32-bit or vice versa?  Do you know for a fact that AMD -> Intel and vice versa can cause problems?  As it stands this is an opinion "reinstall", not a valid fact-supported answer.

Comment: Of course I am not stupid and I know that AMD motherboards dont support intel processors. It is common sense.

Comment: You missed my point - typically just switching motherboards doesn't immediately need a complete reinstallation of the operating system.  With Windows, maybe.  Not as much so with Ubuntu or Linux.

Comment: Not if you are speaking about debian server but you are speaking about home operating systems.